# Mapping form submissions to an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I am creating a form that is used to create the backbone of a website. As such you need to be able to create elements and then send the values of those elements to a server.

My thinking in this is to create two useState arrays each with identical object keys with one array being form fields and the other being the object data that gets sent to the server.

The page loads with either the current list of reviews from the server or one blank review which would in theory fill the first inserted review.

What I want is an onChange method in these text inputs that finds the index of itself in the array of text inputs, then uses that index to find the specific object in the array of the field responses.

So basically if you have 30 sets of input fields and update number 29 it will update number 29 in a corresponding array with the target value. The on change method below works on the first input but as soon as you fire addReview() the values stored in the second array disappear and only the first object in the rev array retains data.

```
 const [revArr, setRevArr] = useState([
    {
      reviewer: (
        <input
          type='text'
          name='reviewer'
          onChange={(e) => {
            rev.map(() => {
              const i = revArr.map((rev, i) => i);
              let obj = {
                reviewer: e.target.value,
                review: rev[i].review,
                date: rev[i].date,
                pic: rev[i].pic,
              };

              rev[i] = obj;
              console.log(firmObj);
            });
          }}
        />
      ),
      date: (
        <input
          type='text'
          name='date'
          onChange={(e) => {
            rev.map(() => {
              const i = revArr.map((rev, i) => i);
              let obj = {
                reviewer: rev[i].reviewer,
                review: rev[i].review,
                date: e.target.value,
                pic: rev[i].pic,
              };

              rev[i] = obj;
            });
          }}
        />
      ),
      review: (
        <input
          type='text'
          name='review'
          onChange={(e) => {
            rev.map(() => {
              const i = revArr.map((rev, i) => i);
              let obj = {
                reviewer: rev[i].reviewer,
                review: e.target.value,
                date: rev[i].date,
                pic: rev[i].pic,
              };

              rev[i] = obj;
            });
          }}
        />
      ),
      pic: (
        <input
          type='text'
          name='pic1'
          onChange={(e) => {
            rev.map(() => {
              const i = revArr.map((rev, i) => i);
              let obj = {
                reviewer: rev[i].reviewer,
                review: rev[i].review,
                date: rev[i].date,
                pic: e.target.value,
              };

              rev[i] = obj;
            });
          }}
        />
      ),
    },
  ]);

  const addReviewObj = () => {
    setReviews([
      ...rev,
      {
        reviewer: "",
        date: "",
        review: "",
        pic: "",
      },
    ]);
    setRevArr([
      ...revArr,
      {
        reviewer: (
          <input
            type='text'
            name='reviewer'
            onChange={(e) => {
              rev.map(() => {
                const i = revArr.map((rev, i) => i);
                let obj = {
                  reviewer: e.target.value,
                  review: rev[i] ? rev[i].review : "",
                  date: rev[i] ? rev[i].date : "",
                  pic: rev[i] ? rev[i].pic : "",
                };

                rev[i] = obj;
              });
            }}
          />
        ),
        date: (
          <input
            type='text'
            name='date'
            onChange={(e) => {
              rev.map(() => {
                const i = revArr.map((rev, i) => i);
                let obj = {
                  reviewer: rev[i] ? rev[i].reviewer : "",
                  review: rev[i] ? rev[i].review : "",
                  date: e.target.value,
                  pic: rev[i] ? rev[i].pic : "",
                };

                rev[i] = obj;
              });
            }}
          />
        ),
        review: (
          <input
            type='text'
            name='review'
            onChange={(e) => {
              rev.map(() => {
                const i = revArr.map((rev, i) => i);
                let obj = {
                  reviewer: rev[i] ? rev[i].reviewer : "",
                  review: e.target.value,
                  date: rev[i] ? rev[i].date : "",
                  pic: rev[i] ? rev[i].pic : "",
                };

                rev[i] = obj;
              });
            }}
          />
        ),
        pic: (
          <input
            type='text'
            name='pic1'
            onChange={(e) => {
              rev.map(() => {
                const i = revArr.map((rev, i) => i);
                let obj = {
                  reviewer: rev[i] ? rev[i].reviewer : "",
                  review: rev[i] ? rev[i].review : "",
                  date: rev[i] ? rev[i].date : "",
                  pic: e.target.value,
                };

                rev[i] = obj;
              });
            }}
          />
        ),
      },
    ]);
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a little confusing but it sounds like you want to have a form with dynamic number of rows. Each row with a fixed number of inputs.

You can keep your state in a single array of objects, mapping over the array to render each row of inputs.

The input onChange handler will pass the array index and the event to a function.

You can get the value and input name from the event, which (along with the array index) is enough information to set the new state.

```
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {

  const emptyReview = {
    reviewer: "",
    review: ""
  };

  const [results, setResults] = useState([{ ... emptyReview }]);

  const onChange = (i, e) => {
    const { value, name } = e.currentTarget;
    const newResults = [...results];
    newResults[i] = {
      ...newResults[i],
      [name]: value
    };
    setResults(newResults);
  };

  const addReview = () => {
    const newResults = [...results, { ... emptyReview }];
    setResults(newResults);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {results.map((result, i) => (
        <div key={i}>
          <div>
            <label>
              reviewer:
              <input
                value={result.reviewer}
                name="reviewer"
                onChange={(e) => onChange(i, e)}
              />
            </label>
          </div>
          <div>
            <label>
              review:
              <input
                value={result.review}
                name="review"
                onChange={(e) => onChange(i, e)}
              />
            </label>
          </div>
          <hr />
        </div>
      ))}
      <button onClick={addReview}>new review</button>
      <pre>{JSON.stringify(results)}</pre>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit adoring-cloud-q04qj]

---

Bonus. If the inputs are just the same text input and label repeated, you could even map over the keys of the object from within the outer map. That way if you ever need to add extra fields, you would just do it in one place - the `emptyReview` object.

```
    {results.map((row, i) => (
      <div key={i} className="row">
        {Object.keys(row).map((key) => (
          <label key={key}>
            {key}
            <input
              value={row[key]}
              name={key}
              onChange={(e) => onChange(i, e)}
            />
          </label>
        ))}
      </div>
    ))}
```

[image: Edit musing-night-yx5pd]

Comment: yes please! while i dont think i was ever gonna get here, i think my heart was in the right place.

Comment: I didnt even see the object keys update, when i refactor to the final form im sure ill revisit that cause this app is so many of these now.  I should reask a question, but do you think you could show how i could stack two of these together. EG creating a quiz is making questions, each question has a set of answers currently trying some stuff, but its not working if you understand the example i want without me hashing out another question. ;-;

Comment: Probably best to make another question so you can better outline your requirements for the quiz. It sounds very similar. It might be a different piece of state or it might be a completely different component. It depends. Feel free a post the link to the new question here.

Comment: i figured it out but thanks for answering. lots of ifs!